# XmlDataSource with XPath - can I get the raw data in code?

Tags: c#, asp.net, data-binding, xmldatasource

If an ASP.NET form has an XmlDataSource on it, and in code I am setting the XPath filter, e.g:

```
xmlExample.XPath = 
     String.Format("data/reasons/reason[@text='{0}']/details/",someValue);
```

... can I then get the result of that XPath filtering in code, or do I **have** to bind to a control to find out the results?

In other words, is it possible to use code to access the xml data that an XmlDataSource is going to return?

Comment: What do you mean by 'raw' data?

Comment: The subset of the XML data that would be returned by the XPath filter.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't actually tried it, but [the documentation for `XmlDataSource.GetXmlDocument`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.xmldatasource.getxmldocument.aspx) (new with .NET 2.0) suggests it will do exactly what you want:

> **Return Value**
>
> An `XmlDataDocument` that represents the XML specified in the `Data` property or in the file identified by the `DataFile` property, with any transformations and `XPath` queries applied.

Comment: That returns the original XML document, but doesn't seem to apply the XPath filter to it (if one is specified)